# Place image in wall

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created a wall using three.js. I want to place an image like in the below example. I am new in three.js, can anyone help me placing the image?

[image: Click here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using sprites to achieve this effect. They don't transform in perspective and always faced to camera. But this is Object3D, you can move them and place whatever you want.

http://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Sprite#Reference/Objects/Sprite

I hope this solution helps you ;).